# Determining video codec via YouTube data API?

Tags: video, youtube

Is it possible to determine whether a particular youtube video is encoded with H.264 or FLV through the YouTube data API? If so, how?

I can start a file download and check how the video stream was encoded (programmatically, of course), but I'd like to use the YouTube data API to avoid all that overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible, and you shouldn't ever need to do this unless you are doing something questionable (with regards to YouTube's API TOS) ;)

If you give more details about what you are trying to do, perhaps there's another solution?

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe this is possible.

You can find the YouTube API reference docs here http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html

Answer (score 1):

If you have the source of a particular video page, you can easily determine what video versions are available.

1. Find the `<embed>` tag with `id` `movie_player`.
2. The `flashvars` attribute of that element contains a html encoded list of `key=value` pairs seperated by `&`. Values are url encoded.
3. Take the value for key `url_encoded_fmt_stream_map` which is a comma seperated list of the video versions you're looking for.
4. Each version is a list of `key=value` pairs seperated by `&`. Values are url encoded.
5. The value for the `itag` key is better known as `fmt` and you can find the different types in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YouTube#Quality_and_codecs)