# Is it possible to get the URL of a YouTube video and load it via AVURLAsset?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, youtube-api, avurlasset

I'm not sure this is possible, but I'm trying to pull a YouTube video into a AVURLAsset using Google's objective-c library.  I've gotten to where I can pull in what I thought were usable video files [from the XML the API returns](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_understanding_video_feeds.html).  They look more or less like this:

```
rtsp://v2.cache8.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQmySUpPeUt7BhMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp
```

Unfortunately, that apparently doesn't work when loaded into an AVURLAsset.  Does anyone know how I might go about getting this to work? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this doesn't work simply because AVURLAsset can't play FLV movies or 3GP movies. Now, YouTube does have other formats, like H.264, but as far as I can tell (though from slightly-outdated information) there's [no way to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316315/determining-video-codec-via-youtube-data-api) [get this version](http://groups.google.com/group/youtube-api-gdata/browse_thread/thread/4c9785d9f9521ffe/5cb6328ccce2dc65), so unfortunately I think this is an impossible task. :(